# Is there a browser support or any plugins, which show the html element's ID or NAME as tooltip while hover in a elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, browser

I want a solution [similar to this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yrojha4ever/t4hZK/5/)

```
$('#field2').attr('title', 'student_Name');
```

but in a other way as i have explained below!
 While testing web programs using browser's developer tools or using firebug plugin, **inspect element** help us to know any elements id or name or whole structure details. 
Now I want  just to see the **selected elements id or name shown as tooltip while hover in any elements without writing any javascript or jquery code**.
 

This requirement is because, my website is in a *Japanese language*.
 All the labels are shown with Japanese text & their id or name attribute's name are in English(*equal to the translated japanese to english ex: 学生名 -> student_Name*). 
 This will help to figure out selected elements english name easily, Without translating its label text to Japanese name.
 I think this will help many programmers, who works in a language other than English as me! 
Is there a browser facility or plugins or any other way to do so?

Comment: [X-Ray](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/x-ray/) add-on for Firefox might help, although it has not been updated recently.

Comment: Voted to close as not constructive. These kind of questions that have no definitive answer are off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write simple CSS debug rule for this:

```
label {
    position: relative;
}
label:hover:after {
    content: attr(for);
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 2px 4px 3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/zMX5w/1/

Comment: Hehe, just wrote almost the same :). `top: 100%;` might work better.

Comment: Yes, styles are up to the OP :)

Comment: Yeah! it works. But still i prefer browser option or plugin if any.